Scan on SSD Hard drive says ok but
Pc repair tech couldn't install Windows 10 on my Windows 7 computer,  he said it was because there were too many writes on my SSD which is only around 5-6 years old.
I came home and tested it, and it said it was ok, but does that still mean there's a problem? There's 4109166 GB host writes. The SSD is 238 GB.
He does not want to install a new OS. He never did tell me why he didn't format the HD.

Thanks

" landing of the aesthetic energy" makes no sense in a computering context

SS added @JoepvanSteen

@JourneymanGeek - I'm limited b/c I'm in Mexico where no one knows anything here. That's why I think my MB was damaged when the other store (different city) put my desktop back together.

I think "landing" may be a bad translation for "grounding". "energy well" may be "voltage core" or even "power supply". reading it that way kinda makes sense, except for "aesthetic". its a questionable answer either way.

if one squints very hard aesthetic = electric?

Since its about "partial" damage etc, i'm assuming they meant static electricity (aesthetic energy) and landing is actually grounding -> They didnt ground properly and static electricity caused damage.

I somehow feel skeptical of your 'computer guy'

He said (this was translated) "change that they did not do the landing of the aesthetic energy well. One can damage a motherboard if it does not make a good landing. In this case, the motherboard is not 100% damaged. If it had been damaged at 100%, the equipment would not turn on."

makes no sense. I'd guess he's trying to sell you a new PC.
Frankly assuming you have a licence (and sadly I don't think the free windows 10 upgrades work any more?), doing a fresh install of windows 10 is simple.

Then he couldn't install Windows 10 on my Windows 7 computer, and he said it was because there were too many writes on my SSD which is only around 5-6 years old.

There is no such thing. Drives can wear out but generally that results in them dying or going read only.

There's 4109166 GB it says. The SSD is 238 GB

this bit seems off, but its hard to tell without knowing what tool was used.

Please tell me do I have to buy a new SSD, because I can't work like this. I went to him with a new MB, CPU & memory & nothing got installed. He also said he can force the Win 10 install, but that means it may crash.

which seems sus

He never did tell me why he didn't format the HD. I thought that was standard when switching OSs, right?

You can do an upgrade in place sometimes, but he didn't?
Absolutely none of this makes sense.
I suggest a second opinion.

You can still upgrade a Windows 7 installation to Windows 10. You just need a Windows 10 license after you perform the upgrade. Windows 7 licenses no longer can be used to activate Windows 10.



He didn't try to sell me on anything. I already have the MB, I just don't have a new HD.


He speaks Spanish & I don't . Google translate isn't great at translating.


I didn't understand what you said about "You can do an upgrade in place sometimes, but he didn't?"


He din't install the new hardware b/c it doesn't work on Win 7, he couldn't put Win 10 on it b/c he was getting an error, so nothing was done in the end.

You can install windows 10 without reformatting windows 7.
